# Would it be possible to configure the WinSCP to start already logged and with the synchronization on?

Tags: windows, sync, login, automation, winscp

I do need that as soon as the computer is turned on, the program WinSCP starts, logs in and synchronizes a local folder with a folder on the server.

That is, there a three distinct points:

1. Get started with Windows (I know how to do this)
2. Log in automatically (I guess using Pageant for authentication will work)
3. Synchronize the folder automatically

I guess that there is no way to complete all items using WinSCP GUI, so I guess that I do need use script... and it is exactly where I'm struggling!

Answer (score 1):

With WinSCP scripting, you can use the following batch file with the [`synchronize` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_synchronize):

```
@echo off

"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^
  /log="C:\writable\path\to\log\WinSCP.log" /ini=nul ^
  /command ^
    "open sftp://user:password@example.com/ -hostkey=""ssh-rsa ...""" ^
    "synchronize local C:\local\path /remote/path" ^
    "exit"
```

WinSCP GUI can [generate a batch file template](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#script) for you.

The above uses a password authentication. If you want to use a public key authentication, use the [`-privatekey` switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_open#privatekey). Pageant won't help you with the automation.

---

With WinSCP GUI, you can use the [`/synchronize` command-line switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#synchronize) like below. Though it has its limitations:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\winscp.exe" session /defaults /synchronize C:\local\path /remote/path
```