# How to automatically sync files in WinSCP?

Tags: ftp, sync, automation, gui, winscp

Is there a way to do that in WinSCP? [The official article about that](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation) only discusses scripting, while I want a simple GUI solution.

Comment: WinSCP might not be the best solution for you, but we need more information. And why is it not enough the Compare directories function to select (highlight) files that are new or different than in the opposite panel?

Comment: You don't give us enough information to provide sage advice.  Is the "other side" also windows? Linux? .. Is FTP a must? ..  .. If I (and others) knew the answer to this question, we might be able to help you more.  In the meantime.. see `rsync` (Linux) and `robocopy` (Windows) .. both of these tools can sync your files.  Also.. if you are using WSL on the windows side, I would also suggest rsync.

Comment: OH.. and GUI tools are often not the best way to party.  Even if you like clickity-clicking on things.. often there are only command line tools to solve your problems.  Reason?  (you ask).. cause the UBER GEEKS that write all of this cool stuff don't USE THEM. ;)

Comment: @harrymc it's just highlighting, not automatically synchronizing? Plus that the local folder containing the file needs to be opened in the left panel. Why do you think WinSCP might not be the best solution for this?

Comment: @Ooker: Better answer Martin Prikryl. He happens to be the author of WinSCP.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas what do you mean by "other side"? The hosting? I don't know. I guess the only way to upload file is FTP? I don't have SSH. Between `robocopy` and WinSCP's scripting, which is better and more convenient?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl preferably as soon as the source file is modified, but when WinSCP starts up and logs in to the FTP is fine

Comment: That's still quite unclear. Do you want to automatically start WinSCP GUI and have it synchronize file, as soon as it changes on your local system – anytime? Or do you want to start WinSCP, login, and then make it automatically watch for changes and upload them? Anyway, most options are covered in [How can I automatically upload code changes on a remote VM](https://superuser.com/q/1385879/213663).

Comment: Other related questions: [It would be possible to configure the WinSCP to start already logged and with the synchronization on?](https://superuser.com/q/1586721/213663) + [Keep FTP folder synchronized with Windows folder](https://superuser.com/q/48782/213663).